# Jquery manipulating Objects that currently have a classtag instead of manipulating the class itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, joomla3.0, responsiveness

So i am currently working on a responsive joomlatemplate, which will replace the navigation bar with a slide navigation as soon as the viewport gets to small. And as in this case I want to keep the navigation bar as long as possible, I proceeded as follows: I created two different css-classes for the navigation and I always assign the one needed via JS. I called those classes "portrait" and "landscape".

So in the css for portrait i got:

```
.portrait .menu li{
width = 100%;
...
}
```

And in the css for landscape i got:

```
.lanscape .menu li{
width = auto;
margin-left = 5px;
margin-right = 5px;
...
}
```

So now i determine the minimum width the navigation has to have in the js-file like this:

```
 var minnavwidth = 0; 
 var navelements = $jQ("#main-navigation").find(".menu").children();
 for (var i = 0; i < navelements.length; i++) {
 minnavwidth += $jQ(navelements[i]).outerWidth(true);
 }
```

But as i want the menuitems in the navigationbar evenly spread out i wrote this in a method that is only fired once:

```
$jQ(".landscape .menu li").css("width", 100 / navelements.length + "%");
```

The problem I have now is, that even after assigning the "portrait"-class to my navigation and also removing the "landscape"-class, the menuitems in the slidemenu still have a 20% width (5 menuitems atm). The only reason i can imagine is, that JQuery assigns the css to the DOMnodes that currently have a class instead of assigning it to the class itself. Is that correct? Is there any way around it other than reassigning the attributes manually every time i am switching classes?

Comment: *"Is that correct"* yes, *"Is there any way around it other than reassigning the attributes manually every time i am switching classes"* no, other than switching from % widths to something more... flexible to eliminate the need for jQuery in this case.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to edit the CSS class properties directly rather than editing the DOM elements that fall under that class.